# ASP.NET Core Identity Primary key performance concerns

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

The default implementation of ASP.NET core uses `Guid` as primary keys for both users and roles tables.

My concern here, is that during DB design, a developer will often need to link  entities to user id as foreign keys, such as adding `ModifiedBy` and `CreatedBy` columns for auditing, in such cases, the foreign key will be an `nvarchar(450)` which is far from efficient compared to an `int` primary key when doing `JOIN`s and other sort of queries.

I know that I can configure identity core to use a custom primary key type such as `int`, but should i stick to the default configuration due to security considerations (am no security expert) ?

Also isn't `JOIN`s on a string foreign key terribly slow compared to `int` foreign key (adding to the mix that the primary key is an `nvarchar` which makes that even worst) ?

P.S: I'm not using code first or EF in general outside the context of ASP.NET core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the default PK type is `string`. It just *looks* like a `Guid`. Regardless, a PK is inherently an indexed column, so it's pretty inconsequential what type it actually is. There is no security concern with using whatever type you like, so if you prefer ints, use ints. Or, you could actually use a true `Guid`, too. In which case, you'll end up with a uniqueidentifier column in the database. Long and short, it's mostly just your personal preference. I do tend to go with ints, though.

Comment: just to make sure I got this correct, so JOINs and queries on an nvarchar indexed column is efficient and won't cause any problems on the long run with 25k users ?

Comment: Yeah. That's sort of the whole point of indexing. Now, the overall size of your database could be affected, but query performance should be roughly the same.

Comment: @sarepta 25K records is nothing for SQL Server. Unless you are doing something completely out of whack, you'll be fine with any type of PK on this scale.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - Can you elaborate on your comment - that just blew my mind!

Comment: An int is 4 bytes (32-bit), whereas a Guid (or something that looks like a Guid) is 32 bytes (technically 36 bytes, since .NET adds dashes). Simply, using Guids for PKs and FKs requires more bytes to encode. For a standard database, the difference would be minimal, likely, but in certain large scale applications it may be something that would have to be considered. However, either way, the column is indexed, so lookups aren't really effected (for the most part) by the size of the value.